# Retrieved all information inside tags : DOMNODE

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a script in which I have no control over the HTML and can only modify the basic CSS. I just wanted to know if it is possible to cut all the information from < script> until its closing </ script> without distinguishing between the elements inside?

First of all I use wp_remote_get (yes it is wordpress) :

```
$response = wp_remote_get("http:localhost/wp/?p={id}");
```

This is what response looks like:

```
array(6) { ["headers"]=> object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#6325 (1) { ["data":protected]=> array(6) { ["date"]=> string(29) "Fri, 04 Feb 2022 08:27:59 GMT" ["server"]=> string(141) "Apache/2.4.48 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2u PHP/8.0.8 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.30.1" ["x-powered-by"]=> string(9) "PHP/8.0.8" ["x-pingback"]=> string(48) "http://localhost:8888/Sadem/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" ["link"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(74) "; rel="https://api.w.org/"" [1]=> string(104) "; rel="alternate"; type="application/json"" [2]=> string(60) "; rel=shortlink" } ["content-type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" } } ["body"]=> string(49331) "
```

And the body ($response["body"]) contains a very simple html page:

1. Links with stylesheets
2. Tags html
3. Links with scripts

And the script :

```
   $content = response['body'];

   $document = new DOMDocument();
   $document->loadHTML($content);

   // An empty array to store all the 'scripts'
   $scripts_array = [];

   // Store every script's line inside the array
   foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) 
    {
       if ($script->hasAttribute('src')) {
           $scripts_array[] = $script->getAttribute('src');
        }
    }
```

Then for you to understand I return the array of all my scripts that I transmit.
I get the array via an api.

Today with my script above I get this:

```
"more_info":{
     "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/js/v4-shims.min.js",
     "http://localhost/wp/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js',
     [...] 
 }
```

But I would like to be able to get this:

```
"more_info":{
     "<script src='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/js/v4-shims.min.js'id='font-awesome-4-shim-js'></script>",
     "<script src='http://localhost/wp/wordpress/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js'id='comment-reply-js'></script>",
     [...] 
}
```

If you haven't understood yet, I'm browsing a page and I want to get all the  lines and I want to put them in an array.

I hope it's clearer for you,

Thank you for your answers ! :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough; again - what does `$content` look like?

Comment: I just added what response is, including response['body'] which I store in $content

Comment: The array you added looks like some kind of `var_dump` and doesn't help. What you need to post is the actual (or sample) html of the document that's in `http:localhost/wp/?p={id}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only the `src` attribute value, because that's all you are asking for in `$script->getAttribute('src')`. Replace your `foreach` with:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($document);
$attribs = $xpath ->query("//script/@*");

foreach ($attribs as $attrib) {     
            $scripts_array[] = $attrib->nodeValue ;            
    }
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I answered you, sorry it was a bit long so I answered my question

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you for your answer! I tried, and I don't get what I want. When I do a query I get this:

```
 "more_info": [
    "http://localhost:8888/Sadem/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/js/v4-shims.min.js?ver=3.5.5",
    "font-awesome-4-shim-js",
     ...and more
]
```

What I was looking for was having the complete line like this:
"more_info": [
"http://localhost/.../assets/lib/font-awesome/js/v4-shims.min.js",
"font-awesome-4-shim-js",
...and more
]

What I was looking for was having the complete line like this:

```
"more_info": [
    "<script src='http://localhost/.../assets/lib/font- 
     awesome/js/v4-shims.min.js' id='font-awesome-4-shim-js'></script>",
     ...and more
]
```

But I thank you again for your help, so few people want to help me....

Comment: What you have here is not what you have in the original question. Maybe you should edit the question and add a short, representative sample of `$content`.

Comment: Thank you again for your interest in my problem, I have just added a new element to improve the understanding of my problem.